# Xamarin/C#/SQlLite - Why is my SUM query returning 'System.Threading.Task'?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin

**Problem:** I have a page which is going to display the results of a variety of SQL queries I'm making against my SQLite DB. This first one is supposed to take the sum of a column and return it. I've used a variety of resources that detail how you make SQL queries and return them as useable variables but I've obviously not been successful. This is currently returning 'System.Threading.Task' as a string. Would love some insight as to where I've gone wrong here.

My DB method to get the sum of the DAYS column:

```
public Task<int> getLeaveDaysSum()
    {
        return _database.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("SELECT SUM(DAYS) from [LeaveEntry]");
    }
```

My OnAppearing method which will update the page label to display the result of the above method:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        LeaveTakenDays.Text = App.Database.getLeaveDaysSum().ToString();
    }
```

As always, if I can provide further details, please let me know. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `await` keyword since this is an async method (and also change the method name with postfix Async)

The `async` modifier specifies that this method is asynchronous and when calling an async method, a task is returned. When the `await` operator is applied to a task, the current method exits immediately. When the task finishes, execution resumes in the same method and this is what was missing in your code.

```
public async Task<int> getLeaveDaysSumAsync()
{
    var count = await _database.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("SELECT SUM(DAYS) from 
[LeaveEntry]");

     return count;
}

protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    var count = await App.Database.getLeaveDaysSumAsync();
    LeaveTakenDays.Text = count.ToString();
}
```

More about async/await can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming

Comment: Thank you, that was it! I've used async methods elsewhere in my project, I just think that I default to standard methods where I don't think something needs to be asynchronous. Lesson learned!

Comment: You're most welcome my friend